# Computable functions vs. provable functions

Tags: logic

A function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{ 0, 1 \} $ is $computable$ if there is a finite algorithm $A$ such that for  any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $A$ produces the output of $f(n)$.

A function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{ 0, 1 \}$ is $provable$ if there is a finite algorithm in which $f$ is the conclusion.

Im curious, do we have $provable \subset computable$? or possible $computable \subset provable$?

Comment: I don't understand your definition of a provable function: what does it mean for a function to be the conclusion of an algorithm? Also, your definition of computable is wrong in a subtle but important way: there has to be *one* algorithm which works for all $n$.

Comment: By provable, we would normally start by fixing a formal system, and they say that a function $f$  is provably total in that system if there is a proof in the system that for all $n$ there exists and $m$ with $f(n)=m$.  I think this could be an interesting question, but I agree it is hard to understand at the moment. You can edit the post to clarify it.

Comment: You can see [Herbrand-Gödel Computability](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZO1p4QGspoYC&pg=PT357&lpg=PA345) for a formalism dealing with sequences of equations $E$ whose aim is "proving" an equation corresponding to a "computable" function. In this case : HG Computability $\equiv$ Turing Computability etc.

Comment: @Noah Schweber, okay did I change it to the correct order?

Comment: @Carl Mummert, yes but isn't it that we can diagonalize out of the primitive recursive functions, and then create a computable total function not primitive recursive? i.e. most likely $provable \subset computable$ because provable is always with respect to a countable formal system

Comment: @PhilipWhite OK, now that's fixed; but what about "provable function"? What, again, does it mean for a function to be the conclusion of an algorithm? I suspect you're asking (as Carl says) about functions which are *provably total* with respect to some fixed system, but that's not at all clear from what you've asked.

Comment: @Philip White: there are really two different topics: functions which are provably total in a particular formal system (a.k.a. "definable functions"), and *total computable* functions which are provably total in a particular formal system. The latter, for any particular effective formal system, will be a subset of the set of total computable functions.  But the former may include non-computable functions. In the literature, when they write "provably total function" they typically mean provably total computable function.  There is a lot that can be said once the definitions are clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still not at all clear what you mean by "provable" function, but here are two reasonable interpretations *(for simplicity, I'll restrict attention to unary functions)*:

- A (a priori computable) function $f$ is *$T$-provably total* if there is some algorithm $A$ which computes $f$ such that $T$ proves that $A$ halts on all inputs. (Note that just because $A$ and $B$ are algorithms computing the same $f$ does *not* mean that $T$ can tell that!)
- A function is *$T$-representable* if there is some formula $\varphi(x,y)$ such that for each natural number $n$, there is exactly one $m$ such that $T$ proves "$\varphi(n, m)$," and this $m$ is exactly $f(n)$. 
  (I'm being a bit sloppy here, but not in any essential way.)

Now suppose $T$ is "reasonable" - say, a sound computably axiomatizable consistent extension of (first-order) Peano arithmetic. Then we have:

- **The $T$-provably total functions form a proper subclass of the computable functions.** This is an easy diagonalization argument, since we can effectively enumerate the algorithms which $T$ proves are total (and since $T$ is sound they are in fact total so our diagonalization never "gets stuck").
- **The $T$-representable functions coincide with the computable functions.** Clearly every representable function is computable since $T$ is computably axiomatizable (just search through $T$-proofs); the converse involves coding Turing machines in the language of arithmetic, and is often proved along the way in modern presentations of Godel's incompleteness theorem. (What Godel needed of course was much less - that *primitive recursive* functions are representable - but the stronger statement here is true as well.)

---

Note that while the above argument shows that *representability strength* isn't going to be a useful criterion with which to distinguish theories, *provable totality* is quite a different matter. Indeed, there is a lot of work done in proof theory on classifying the computable functions provably total in a given "reasonable" theory, as a way of gaining deeper understanding of that theory:

- The theory $I\Sigma_1$ is a weak fragment of PA which is still strong enough for the development of "basic logic" (and as such is used as the arithmetic part of the standard base theory in [reverse mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics)). The $I\Sigma_1$-provably total computable functions are exactly the primitive recursive functions.
- This already far outstrips the classes of functions of interest to complexity theorists; theories of arithmetic which are closer connected to complexity theory in this regard are studied under the general name "bounded arithetic," and if you're interested [these slides of Buss](https://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/StPetersburg_BoundedArith_2016/talkAllSlides_Corrected.pdf) might be a good starting point.
- The theory PA is of course much stronger than $I\Sigma_1$ (and indeed is strong enough that natural examples of principles undecidable in PA are quite interesting), and the class of PA-provably total computable functions is correspondingly extremely large; [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsl/1146620058) is one analysis of this class by Weiermann.
- All of this is tightly bound up with [ordinal analysis](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~rathjen/ICMend.pdf), and this is visible in Weiermann's treatment of PA mentioned above.